# Cant clone git repository

Tags: windows, git

first-time asker here. I have an issue with git, cant clone anything. If I don't specify where to clone, this will appear.

```
> git clone https://gitlab.corp.cz/username/project_name.git project_name
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'project_name': No such file or directory
```

If I first create a folder via explorer, then the error message is different.

```
> git clone https://gitlab.corp.cz/username/project_name.git project_name
Cloning into 'project_name'...
C:/Users/username/Documents/project/path/.git: No such file or directory
```

Mkdir say the same, though not sure if windows even have a mkdir. At least a month ago, it worked. Please help, even reinstalled windows, didn't help.

**EDIT:** It looks like it is not a git problem. I cannot create any file using nothing other than windows explorer. Checked and I have write permissions for this folder, so most likely a windows problem.

Comment: If it worked a month ago, something may have messed with your %PATH% environment variable since.  You likely had a set of tools you were using with git (gitbash cygwin).  Check using "where git.exe" and "echo %PATH%" (without quotes) to give an idea of what might be going on.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour] and read [ask].  Please [edit] your post to include the exact git clone command line.  Obfuscating secrets is okay, just make it clear what parts you obfuscated.

Comment: Edited the post according to jwdonahue. Abel since I have clean install, shouldn't it work normally? Location from where git.exe is in %PATH% variable.

Answer (score 0):

**a)** You must run the command in a directory where you have write permission;

**b)** Add git to the list of allowed applications:

1 - Select Start  > Settings  > Update & Security  > Windows Security > Virus & threat protection.

2 - Under Virus & threat protection settings, select Manage settings.

3 - Under Controlled folder access, select Manage Controlled folder access.

4 - Switch the Controlled folder access setting to On or Off.

**c)** If that doesn't work, try running the terminal with the administrator.

Comment: Neither of your tips works, some of them I tried even before asking. The folder is inside a Documents folder of windows, I have edited the question so it is clear. This is a fresh install of windows, no changes to write permissions, just created folder and tried to clone  to it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) to execute this command in the terminal check if the linux user has permissions to create a new folder there or try doing it as root.

If you are using Powershell or the Command Prompt try running it as Administrator and check if cloning a repo will work.. if this works there is a problem with your permissions. In this case try to change your working path so if the folder you are trying to clone a repo is in "C:\Program Files" or "C:\Program Files (x86)" try cloning to another place as these paths cause problems.